# How to extract the important variables from stepAIC in R to an excel sheet?

Tags: r, lm

```
lmModel <- lm(y~.,data.frame(y=y, x=x))
step <- stepAIC(lmModel, direction="both")
step$anova
```

Stepwise Model Path Analysis of Deviance Table

Initial Model:

```
y ~ x.Market.Price + x.Quantity + x.Country + x.Incoterm + x.Channel +
x.PaymentTerm
```

Final Model:

```
y ~ x.Quantity + x.Country + x.Incoterm + x.PaymentTerm
```

Question:

Now, $anova list the final model only on the console.

How do I retrieve the variable names of final model to an excel sheet?

For example

as.formula(step)

gives me the final variable data. How do you write this to an excel sheet as it is not a dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Try `model.matrix(step)`. This will give you a data.frame of the selected variable which you can write to any text file and import to excel.

Comment: I get "java heap space" error while I run model.matrix(step) inside a function, where I am using XLConnect package

Comment: From http://www.statmethods.net/input/exportingdata.html: you can use `library(xlsx); write.xlsx(mydata, "c:/mydata.xlsx")`

Comment: that did not help me either. any other options? For example as.formula(step) gives me the final variable data. How do you write this to an excel sheet as it is not a dataframe.

Comment: You can also export as CSV using `write.csv(model.matrix(step), file = "...")` and open that CSV in your excel.

Comment: The problem is not with extracting to CSV or Excel file. 'as.formula(step)' is not getting exported to excel sheet as it is not in data.frame format.